# Copying only first 2 dimensions of 3D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following 3D array set up as a buffer between two program states.

```
private boolean state [][][] = new boolean [20][20][2];
```

I'm trying to copy everything from

```
state[0-19][0-19][1]
```

to

```
state[0-19][0-19][0]
```

At the moment I'm using a for loop, which works fine, but I can't help feeling that there's a better way. I know I could just use two separate 2D arrays and do a simple copy, but I'm interested to see if there's any way around this.

Current loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<20;j++){
            state[i][j][0]=state[i][j][1];
    }
}
```

Comment: To know if it can be done better than what you have, we actually have to see what you have.

Comment: To me a for loop makes sense.  What would you call 'better'?  faster?

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx I suppose I'm looking for something more efficient. I know System.arraycopy() can do the job for separate arrays, but I can't get it to work within a single array

Comment: Why do you want to copy? Do you want 2 set of duplicate value? Or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you can replace the inner loop with `System.arraycopy`, which will then be faster. But not in your memory layout, I believe.

If possible, instead of copying the array, consider updating the references. Recall that "multidimensional" arrays in java are actually arrays of arrays.

In particular,

```
 boolean[] tmp = multi[0];
 multi[0] = multi[1];
 multi[1] = tmp;
```

*swaps* the two array references at next-to-zero cost. This is *much* faster than copying, and then overwriting the old values. But sometimes you need a copy (if you don't overwrite the old values), then you can't do this.

Note that you shouldn't do this blindly:

```
 multi[0][0] = 1;
 multi[1] = multi[0];
 multi[1][0] = 0;
 System.err.println(multi[0][0]);
```

will print `0`, because now `multi[0]` and `multi[1]` point to the same nested array, and you should have used.

```
 multi[1] = multi[0].clone();
```

Note that also cloning is not *deep*, so `multi.clone()` will point to the same nested arrays as `multi`. There is no built-in deep clone or deep arraycopy in Java, you need to use a loop for that either way.

But again, none of these supposedly work if you want to copy the second element to the first in *lots of arrays*. This is a problem of your memory layout.

Recall what your data structure looks like in memory:

```
 boolean[][][] -> boolean[][] -> boolean[]{ 0, 1 }
              \               \> boolean[]{ 0, 1 }
               \> boolean[][] -> boolean[]{ 0, 1 }
                              \> boolean[]{ 0, 1 }
```

you want to copy *one element in each array*. They can be *all across your memory* (every `boolean[]...` is an object of its own!), so there is no way to speed this up with primitives - the data is scattered. Maybe **consider changing your memory layout**, if possible.

Also consider alternatives to *boolean* arrays. Booleans take 1 byte of memory, but store only one bit (note that this can be faster, so it's not bad per se!). But sometimes it makes sense to instead store the whole boolean array in a `BitSet` or a `long`, and then work with actual bit operations. But gain, sometimes it does pay, sometimes it hurts.

Comment: Note that this is 3 dimensional. `clone` will only produce a shallow copy for 2D array from what I tested. Your first method will only work when the array is declared differently (`[2]` is the first dimension, instead of being the last one).

Comment: @nhahtdh I don't see how your link relates or contradicts what I said.

Comment: The question asks about 3D, your example uses 2D array. There are some difference in how it should be handled. 1) Swapping reference can only be done when you rearrange the dimensions `[2][20][20]` 2) `multi.clone() != multi`, but `multi.clone()[1] == multi[1]` due to sharing of subarray. The subarrays are shared, according to [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7). 3) `clone` works for `multi[0]` (returns a copy, since `multi[0]`'s type is 1D array), but it is potentially confusing, since OP is working with 3D array.

Comment: You are welcome to add in the extra dimension. It does not change much. Only the last dimension is a "native" array. Any higher dimension is rugged. As for `multi.clone` I explicitely state that they refer to the same arrays, and the copy is not deep.

Comment: That's where you are wrong (or the wording is extremely confusing). `multi.clone` is different from `multi`, only the sub arrays are shared.

Comment: But that is exactly what I'm saying.., `multi.clone()` points to the same subarrays.

Answer (score 0):

I like nhahtdh's solution of reorganising the dimensions, but beware that if you copy the reference, then if you later change `state[0]`, `state[1]` will reflect the change, and vice versa (which, mind you, may actually be what you want). The reference will be accessible in 2 places but store contents in only one place - old pointer/reference confusion. Unit tests are your friend :-)

If you have a **single** dimension array, the `Arrays.copyOf()` method can help to avoid some looping code. But remember that a copy of some `sometype[]` object will copy the **reference** to the object, not all the individual `sometype` objects.

You could of course start playing around with `.clone()` or even Serialization to get "deep" copies of a `sometype[]` object, but then that gets more complicated than your nested loops quickly.

Comment: The method I proposed is not copying, but **swapping**. Making true copy will require looping somewhere. I didn't suggest direct assignment, so no funny stuff will happen.